# Cordova 3.5 ContactFindOption to search contact by phonenumber

Tags: cordova, contacts

I want to search contacts by phonenumber. I am using code:

```
 function onSuccess(contacts) {
    console.log(contacts)
};

function onError(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
};

// find all contacts with given phone number
var options = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter="9427831147";
options.multiple=false; 
var fields = ["phoneNumber"];
navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
```

I found that

> filter: Property can only apply to the following: "firstName",
>   "lastName", "nickname", "phoneNumber", "email", "address"

on 
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html

I am not getting any result. 

Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Adroid I tested successfully with onSuccess and fields placed differently, like this:

```
navigator.contacts.find(onSuccess, onError, fields, options);
```

Which contradicts the manual but it works.

It is phoneNumbers with s in the end, not phoneNumber.

Comment: no first parameter is accepted as array and not function. This throws error